# SQLite select statement is not working

Tags: android, select, android-sqlite

I have written a method for whether data is saved. Method must return false but it return true. My codes are here;

```
private boolean baskaVarMi(String gelenTarih) {

    boolean sonuc = false;
    int k = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbo.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "select * from gunlukler where tarih='" + gelenTarih + "'";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("tarih")) == gelenTarih) {
                k++;
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    if (k > 0) {
        sonuc = true;
    }else if(k == 0){
        sonuc = false;
    }

    return sonuc;
}
```

What is the problem in this method?

Comment: When you want to compare strings, you have to use `equals()` method. But in your scenario there is no reason for your second condition e.q. `if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("tarih")) == gelenTarih)` You don't need it but if you still want to use it so use `equals()` Also i recommend to use parametrized statements and not hard-coded.

Comment: I agree with Sajmon , SQLite is so rushy, use parametrized statements,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change with it:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
if (c.getCount()>0) {
c.moveToFirst()
    do {
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("tarih")).equals(gelenTarih)) {
            k++;
        }
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way....

```
Cursor cur = db.query(SQL_TABLE, new String[] { URLNAME,ID,URLVALUE }, null, null,
            null, null, null); // query..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("tarih")) == gelenTarih
```

is not right. Go with

```
   c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("tarih")).equals( gelenTarih)
```

Answer (score 0):

use only this

```
private boolean baskaVarMi(String gelenTarih) {
SQLiteDatabase db = dbo.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "select * from gunlukler where tarih='" + gelenTarih + "'";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) 
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```